# uiswitch state change issue

Tags: ios, swift, uiswitch

I have a switch, I want to restrict toggle based on some condition. 
how can we restrict switch state change based on some condition? I also tried setOn in DispatchQueue.main.async.

```
if sender.isOn{
      self.pmLabel.textColor = UIColor.ktvPurple()
      self.amLabel.textColor = UIColor.lightGray

      if let pmTime = self.eveningShowtime{
        updateClock(from: CGFloat(pmTime), to: CGFloat(pmTime) + CGFloat(durationsHours))
        updatePieChart()
      }else{
        self.view.makeToast("Evening Shows are not available", duration: 1.0, position:CGPoint(x: SCREENWIDTH/2, y: SCREENHEIGHT - 180))
        ampmSwitch.isOn = false
      }

    }else{
      self.amLabel.textColor = UIColor.ktvPurple()
      self.pmLabel.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
      if let morningTime = self.morningShowTime{
        updateClock(from: CGFloat(morningTime), to: CGFloat(morningTime) + CGFloat(durationsHours))
        updatePieChart()
      }else{
        self.view.makeToast("Morning Shows are not available", duration: 1.0, position:CGPoint(x: SCREENWIDTH/2, y: SCREENHEIGHT - 180))
        ampmSwitch.isOn = true

      }




    }
```

Comment: You can do `theSwitch.enabled = true/false` to allow the user to click on it according to your conditions. It should be "grayed out" then showing the user that it can't change its value.

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
if yourCondition {
    yourSwitch.enabled = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use userInteractionEnabled or enabled properties for your switch.

Comment: It's a correct answer, but the issue is that it's unclear for the user. He/She doesn't know why the switch value can't be changed while changing `enabled` property should show it to the user.